# How to merge two cells, add a space and a comma

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, worksheet-function

I have two cells:

Cell 1 - `Toronto`
Cell 2 - `ON`

I want to merge into one cell and have it say `Toronto, ON` (adding a `,` and space after Toronto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Cell 1 is A1 and Cell 2 is B1, please try:

```
 =A1&", "&B1
```

I think you want to [CONCATENATE](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/CONCATENATE-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) rather than merge (which is best avoided at all costs).

An alternative version is:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,", ",B1)
```